# Redirecting not working properly in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a mobile app using jQuery mobile. I want a user to be redirected to a specific page on entering a search query. For example, if a user types xyz, he should be redirected to #xyz.

My code:

```
<form onsubmit="queryRedirect()">
    <input type="search" id="search_bar" placeholder="Type a string">
</form>

function queryRedirect() {
var page = document.getElementById('search_bar').value;
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + page);
return false;
}
```

It does redirect, as expected, but the problem is, that the new page lasts only for 1-2 seconds, and then it automatically comes back to the home page.. Plz help me solve this..

Comment: Just add `preventDefault()` at the beginning of the function to prevent page from redirecting when form is submitted.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do.

Use `location.href = '#'+page;`

Check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/f44kf0kh/1/)**.

Here is the snippet.

```js
function queryRedirect() {
  var page = document.getElementById('search_bar').value;
  location.href = '#' + page;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return queryRedirect()">
    <input type="search" id="search_bar" placeholder="Type a string" />
</form>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id='xyz'>
    hh
</div>
```

Comment: This part of code doesn't even use jQuery. That doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: And it is working fine on Chrome on my Android mobile. Note that I have changed the `onsubmit` attribute's value. I have added `return` before the function name. That prevents it from submitting the form.